# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found

Tags: laravel, mongodb, ubuntu, driver, jenssegers-mongodb

I followed this commands.

$ sudo pecl install mongodb

$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb

```
 use MongoDB\Client AS Mongo; 
 $mongo = new Mongo();
```

I am using NGNIX and ubuntu 20. In localhost it is working but in server it is not. In localhost I am using apache2 and in server there ngnix.

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

On you're server, first check whether `mongodb` extension module is loaded by PHP or not

```
php -i | grep mongo
```

If there is no output, then check whether `mongodb` client is installed or not by this command

```
pecl list mongodb
```

If no output then installed `mongodb` client

```
pecl install mongodb
```

Once installed, add this line `extension=mongodb.so` in `php.ini` file.

Restart nginx webserver and If you're application is using `php-fpm` restart this service too

Once, everything is at its place, you can re-verify the module is loaded or not using `php -i` or `php -m` command